# How to cite (results of) a competition held in conference venue?

Tags: citation-style

I want to cite results of a competition that is held in a conference venue. I've seen [a related question here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124105/how-to-reference-the-results-of-kaggle-and-other-similar-competitions-in-an-acad?newreg=a46458c6791c4aa380c7288cd03684be) of citing Kaggle competition results. An answer suggested to do general citation because of the anonymity and the changing nature of the results in Kaggle competition. However, differing with Kaggle competition, results of a competition in venues such as a conference cannot change with new incoming method/answer submission. Therefore, what's the proper way to cite this? is there a bibtex entry for this?

Comment: Do you want to cite results in general or that of a specific method?

Comment: results of all the method to all of the problems

Comment: The important thing about citations is that a reader can follow your citation to check what you say and potential background. So this depends on where something is written down and later retrievable about that competition.

Comment: @ChristianHennig so we could just cite the url of the competition results page? or make it a footnote?

Comment: Only if you have nothing better. URLs can become defunct, so it's not optimal, but better than nothing.